# What is "prime minister to replace him" modifying?

Tags: grammaticality

I am currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/johnson-challenge-queen-fire-him-001723083.html) and one line says,

> Johnson would not step aside if his Brexit proposals were rejected by the European Union, and even if members of the U.K. Parliament declare no confidence in his government and **agree to a caretaker prime minister to replace him,** according to the report.

I don' t understand what the line "prime minister to replace him" is modifying.

Because the line is in the If clause, and "If A XXX (verb (here it is "agree to a caretaker))" is correct, then the modifier "prime minister to replace him" is wrong because there is no need to mention "him", which is the caretaker, and which is already mentioned.

Comment: The problem is with the word "and" before "even". If this is replaced with "nor", things make more sense. "A caretaker prime minister to replace him" is not a modifier, but a complement of "to". "Him" simply refers to "Johnson".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts of the grammar here that might be confusing: "agree to" and "caretaker prime minister".

### agree to a <noun>

Here's a simpler sentence with "agree to a <noun>":

> Tom Jeffords persuaded Cochise to **agree to a meeting** with General Gordon Granger in September 1871. The meeting was held near Victorio's favorite camp site, Ojo Caliente. ([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=DPcv5BzLhCoC&lpg=PT52&dq=%22agree%20to%20a%20meeting%22&pg=PT52#v=onepage&q=%22agree%20to%20a%20meeting%22&f=false), slightly edited.)

The exact meaning of this phrase can vary a lot depending on the noun. It's always possible to restate the meaning in the form **agree to <verb>**, but it usually requires more words. In this example, Cochise agreed to come to a meeting. If you "agree to a reduced price," you might agree to sell something at a lower price than the price at which you sold it before, or lower than a price previously discussed, depending on context.

### caretaker prime minister

The word "caretaker" is an attributive noun modifying "prime minister". A [caretaker prime minister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caretaker_government) is a person appointed to serve temporarily as prime minister during a transitional period between the dissolution of the government and the next election. A caretaker prime minister usually has more limited powers than a normally elected prime minister.

### agree to a caretaker prime minister to replace him

So, **him** refers to Boris Johnson, not the caretaker. The phrase **to replace him** modifies **caretaker prime minister**. It's actually redundant, because the only reason a caretaker prime minister would be appointed would be to serve as Boris Johnson's replacement until new elections determine a new prime minister.

The phrase **agree to a caretaker prime minister** is poorly chosen, because **agree to a <noun>** normally means to make a compromise with another party. When parliament "agrees to" a caretaker prime minister, they simply choose the caretaker prime minister by voting among themselves. Boris Johnson gets no say in the matter.

The whole original sentence is somewhat clumsily written. Another problem is that the word "and" is confusing; it should be "nor". Here is a rewrite, broken into two sentences:

> If the European Union were to reject Boris Johnson's Brexit proposals, he would not step aside. Johnson will not step aside even if Parliament declares no confidence in his government and chooses a caretaker prime minister to replace him.

This is an extraordinary claim—which may explain some of the unusual wording. It means that Boris Johnson has declared that he will not follow the British constitution. Under the British constitution, the prime minister is chosen by parliament and serves only as long as he or she "enjoys the confidence" of parliament. If parliament declares that it has [no confidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_of_no_confidence) in the government, then the prime minister is supposed to resign. Normally that goes without saying. If Johnson won't resign, then the Queen must officially dismiss him. Customarily, the Queen is not supposed to do anything except what the prime minister advises her to do. Using her official authority to dismiss a prime minister against his will is a last resort—a test of power that goes outside the U.K.'s normal democratic processes.

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, what benefit would Boris Johnson get if the parliament agree to "a caretaker prime minister to replace"?

Comment: @KentaroTomono He would get no benefit at all. He would not even be part of the agreement. This is why "agree to" is a poor word choice here. The meaning is: Parliament decides to remove Boris Johnson from office and replace him with someone else. If your boss fires you and replaces you with someone else, we don't normally call this "agreeing". (I think "agree" was chosen to refer to the deliberations among the members of Parliament, not including Boris Johnson.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really *modifying* anything, but it is the other half of the two-part phrase with the subject "members of the UK Parliament".  We can rephrase:

> Even if members of the UK Parliament [do various things], Johnson would not step down.

Personally I find the use of "would" to be odd.  Instead I prefer "will", because this is a fairly definite future possibility:

> Boris Johnson **will** refuse to step down, even if ...